# Detecting Which button was pressed within a custom UITableCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I currently have a custom cell in which I have 3 buttons connected to my custom cell with an `IBOutlet`. The issue I am having is during testing when I press any of the buttons within the cell, all the buttons are pressed. I think this is caused by the way I have set up handling when each of the buttons are pressed:

```
cell.FTCOne.tag = indexPath.section
cell.FTCOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(oneSelected), for: .touchUpInside)

cell.FTCTen.tag = indexPath.section
cell.FTCOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tenSelected), for: .touchUpInside)

cell.FTCTwenty.tag = indexPath.section
cell.FTCOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(twentySelected), for: .touchUpInside)
```

I assume this is caused because they all have the same tag. If that is the case what is the best way of identifying the `indexPath` of the row the user has selected?

Comment: start var names with small letter

Comment: You’re calling `addTarget` for `FTCOne` three times.

Comment: FWIW, I would not recommend using `tag` to capture the `section`. What if you later insert a section? It’s much better to pass the `UITableViewCell` reference back to the view controller and then let it determine the section (and row) for that cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You incorrectly added the targets

```
cell.fTCOne.tag = indexPath.section
cell.fTCOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(oneSelected), for: .touchUpInside)

cell.fTCTen.tag = indexPath.section
cell.fTCTen.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tenSelected), for: .touchUpInside)

cell.fTCTwenty.tag = indexPath.section
cell.fTCTwenty.addTarget(self, action: #selector(twentySelected), for: .touchUpInside)
```